# Asp.net MVC application cannot be hosted and working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am facing a problem that has not been resolved so far and do it over three weeks. I am supposed to create a web application that do the following:

1- Allow the user to select the search criteria from drop down list and click the export button.
2- The button click event calls an API that in its turn fetches the data from the data store based on search criteria, opens an existing Excel template file and fill it with the returned data, and save it with a new name (i.e, original template named abc.xlsx and it will saved as abc[date]-[time].xlsx).
3- Finally download the newly created Excel file.

I created the application and on the development environment it did the first two steps successfully, when I tired to deploy the application on either my local machine IIS, or on the production server IIS the application did only the first step and part of the second one (i.e., fetching the data from the data store), however, the rest of steps cannot be achieved. Here's my code:

```
$("#dataexporter").click(function () {
    if ($("#countrycriteria").val().toString() === "0" || $("#productcriteria").val().toString() === "0") {
        $('from').append('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Please make sure you select all required fields!</div >');
    }
    else {
        $('div[class*="alert-warning"]').remove();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $.ajax("api/exportify/export?countrycriteria=" + $("#countrycriteria").val().toString() + "&productcriteria=" + $("#productcriteria").val().toString(), {
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (response !== null)
                    window.location.href = JSON.parse(response).downloadurl

                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('An error occurred ' + errorThrown);
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }
});

[RoutePrefix("api/exportify")]
public class ExportController : BaseController
{
    private IExporterProvider provider;
    private Invoker invoker;

    public ExportController()
    {
        switch (AppConfiguration.ExporterProvider)
        {
            case "excel":
                provider = new ExcelExporterProvider();
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        invoker = new Invoker();
        invoker.Commands.Add(provider.GetExporter());
    }

private IEnumerable<Analytics> GetData(string countrycriteria, string productcriteria)
    {
        return helper.SelectByCountryAndProduct(countrycriteria, productcriteria);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> GetResponseContent()
    {
        string fname = AppConfiguration.SaveAsName;
        int lastBackslash = fname.LastIndexOf("\\");
        int substringLength = fname.Length - lastBackslash;
        string filename = fname.Substring(lastBackslash + 1, substringLength - 1);

        return new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { "downloadurl", Path.Combine(AppConfiguration.ServerAddress, AppConfiguration.Temporaryfolder, filename + AppConfiguration.FileExtension) }
        };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("export")]
    public IHttpActionResult Export(string countrycriteria, string productcriteria)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Analytics> data = (List<Analytics>)GetData(countrycriteria, productcriteria);
            if (data.Count > 0)
            {
                data.ForEach(d => DeterminetheCategory(d));

                foreach (var Command in invoker.Commands)
                {
                    Command.ExportedData = data;
                }

                invoker.Execute();

                return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetResponseContent()));
            }
            else
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, string.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code that will be ultimately executed when the invoker.Execute(); statement being hit:

```
public class ExcelExporter
{
    protected static void ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<Analytics> data)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppConfiguration.Temporaryfolder, AppConfiguration.Filename + AppConfiguration.FileExtension)))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found.\nThe requested analytical.xlsx was not found on the server");
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsx = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook workbook = null;
        Worksheet worksheet = null;

        try
        {
            workbook = xlsx.Workbooks.Open(
            Filename: Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppConfiguration.Temporaryfolder, AppConfiguration.Filename + AppConfiguration.FileExtension),
            ReadOnly: false);
            worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
            List<Analytics> list = (List<Analytics>)data;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("A{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].ProductShare;
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("B{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].MarketPotential;
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("C{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].RepresnentativeName;
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("D{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].DoctorName;
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("E{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].CustomerCode;
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("F{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].Specialization;
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("G{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].ProductName;
                worksheet.Range[string.Format("H{0}", i + 2)].Value = list[i].Category;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error while processing file", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            AppConfiguration.SaveAsName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppConfiguration.Temporaryfolder, AppConfiguration.Filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss"));
            workbook.SaveAs(Filename: AppConfiguration.SaveAsName, FileFormat: XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
            workbook.Close(SaveChanges: true);
            xlsx.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlsx);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how the IIS features being selected/installed on either my local machine IIS or the production server IIS:

```
Web Management Tools -> IIS Management Console
World Wide Web Services
Application Development Features -> .NET Extensibility 3.5, .NET Extensibility 4.7, ASP.NET 3.5, ASP.NET 4.7, CGI, ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters
Common HTTP Features -> Default Document, Direct Browsing, HTTP Errors, Static Content
Health and Diagnostics -> HTTP Logging
Performance Features -> Static Content Compression
Security -> Request Filtering
```

I also gave both the **IIS_IUSERS**/**Administrators** a full control permissions on the publish folder on which the **IIS** website is directed.

I also configured the following Component Services for Excel

```
Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft 
Excel Application -> Properties
Authentication Level -> None
Security
Launch and Activation Permissions** -> Customize -> 
Administrators/IIS_IUSERS have full permissions
Access Permissions -> Customize -> Administrators/IIS_IUSERS have full 
permissions
Configure Permissions -> Customize -> Administrators/IIS_IUSERS have full 
permissions
```

I am still having problems starting at opening the existing Excel template file template which blocking the rest of steps of the application from being executed as I have to open the file, fill it with the data, save it with a new name, then download the newly created file!.

Comment: What error/exception do you get?

Comment: what is the "Identity" for application pool under which the application executes? does that user have proper access rights on the folder from where you are reading excel template, and writing file in the disk?

Comment: I added both my account and local account, beside the other mentioned users listed above (i.e., IIS_IUSERS and Administrator), to have full control using the security tab for both the external folder, the publish folder and  the temp folder where both the existing template reside and the new created on will be written!. Folders are located in C drive

Comment: @Amr.Mohammad87 It is very interesting that you have given all of the information regarding to the app except from the error or the problem that is most necessary for fixing the problem...

Comment: The problem occurs at the finally block. The exception detail state that the exception being thrown when attempting to execute the following line: workbook.SaveAs(Filename: AppConfiguration.SaveAsName, FileFormat: XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);.

Comment: Exception details "ClassName": "System.NullReferenceException",
    "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "Data": null, "InnerException": null, "HelpURL": null, "StackTraceString": "at WebDataExporter.WebCore.Core.ExcelExporter.ExportToExcel(IEnumerable`1 data) in E:\\Demo\\WebDataExporter\\WebDataExporter.WebCore\\Core\\Adaptee\\ExcelExporter.cs:line 48\r\n etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out that you will always go in troubles if you are hosting an application that uses the Microsoft Office through COM. I used an third party XML based API instead [EPPlus](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=epplus) and it works very well for me even I do not have to install Microsoft Office at the hosting machine.